# Payment verification via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, payment

Im trying to make Graph API call via C#

```
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);    
var response = fb.Get("paymentID?access_token=appID|appSecret") as IDictionary<string,  object>;
```

I manage to get correct result with Graph API Explorer, but in C# project, I get following error message: "(OAuthException - #1151) (#1151) Requires application to be payments enabled or the phone support app"

Answer (score 0):

Set access_token = App Token from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/
Check payments enabled in [https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[app_id]/payments/](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/%5bapp_id%5d/payments/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you use correct values of appID and appSecret? Seems they are incorrect (if graph says OK, and your FacebookClient in up-to-date, so, problem in token)